# Are there compatibility issues when using this.constructor from with a constructor invocation to access static properties?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I'd like to use a constructor's static properties during initialization as such:

```
var MyConstructor = function() {
  this.foo = 'foo';
  this.set_bar();
}

MyConstructor.bar = "bar";

MyConstructor.prototype = {
  set_bar: function() {
    this.bar = this.constructor.bar;
  }
}

var myObj = new MyConstructor();
```

This seems to work just fine in new browsers, but does it fail in old browsers? I've been having trouble finding this out on Google. I'm wondering whether some browsers set `this.constructor` after construction, such that the property is not available during construction.

Comment: Why don't you put `bar` as an instance property just like `foo`? What's the purpose of doing what you're doing?

Comment: I'm using such code in conjunction with Backbone and Backbone's `extend`; I want to keep some things as properties of the constructor for clarity.

Comment: This was a very confused question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no setting properties, they are looked up on the object. If the property isn't on the object, it's looked up on the object's prototype object. If it's not on the object's prototype object, it's looked up on the object's prototype object's prototype object and so on.

Your code does not work as expected because `MyConstructor.prototype =` overwrites the default prototype object which has the proper constructor. So `MyConstructor.prototype` does not have a `constructor` property and neither does `myObj`. So `this.constructor === Object`, not `MyConstructor`. `Object.bar` is `undefined`, and so is `myObj.bar` as a consequence.

The fix is either extending the default prototype instead of overwriting, or reinserting the constructor:

```
MyConstructor.prototype = {
    set_bar: function() {
        this.bar = this.constructor.bar;
    },

    constructor: MyConstructor
}
```

Comment: I guess Backbone's `extend` is already doing this for me: `var Surrogate = function(){ this.constructor = child; };
    Surrogate.prototype = parent.prototype;
    child.prototype = new Surrogate;`

Comment: Yeah it is extending instead of overwriting like you are doing in the OP

Comment: @dimadima yes, `MyConstructor.prototype =` overwrites. Another consequence of overwriting is that already existing objects are pointing to the old prototype object and thus don't get the methods in the overwriting prototype object.

Comment: I mean, I guess so, but in the code above I've got a function that's the result of a function expression, so overwriting its prototype with an object literal isn't really overwriting is it? Do I lose something this way? I intentionally left Backbone out of the question because this isn't Backbone related.

Comment: @dimadima you lose the original prototype object which had the proper constructor property. In the overwriting prototype you need to re-establish it like I have shown. You can see that `myObj.bar` is `undefined` in your code.

Comment: Anyway, my code is working as expected. I'm wondering about browser compatibility for using `this.constructor` as shown exactly above.

Comment: @dimadima no it isn't, `myObj.bar` is `undefined` http://jsfiddle.net/uY2tN/. See with the fix: http://jsfiddle.net/uY2tN/1/

Comment: Wait you're totally right. I may have an error in my code. That's not what I was trying to show :D

Comment: @dimadima well if you use the fix there is no issue like I explained. `.constructor` is not magical in any way. And a constructor call works very much like any other function call.

Comment: I see. So this is a non-question? This must be why I was having trouble Googling this. I swear I Googled it, and I thought JavaScript set `this.constructor`, and the Backbone setting of `this.constructor` was just so that the logically correct object would be referenced there. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor